# Intellisnese for node.js in WebStorm

Tags: node.js, express, visual-studio-code, webstorm, intellisense

I'm having trouble with intellisense in WebStorm for express package and also for sequelize package. I have also tried VS code and problem there is same. For example with imported package

```
const express = require('express');
const app = express();
```

then I get no suggestion for `app.get()` or any other method. Even worst I get the `get()` method underline in WebStorm with warning saying **Unresolved method or function**

[image]

Code runs fine though. There are also other problems with other packages like sequelize. I kinda managed to fixed express intellisense by adding .application in import which however crash the app

```
const express = require('express').application;
```

Another approach I tried was to add enable after initialisation. That doesn't crash the app and intellisense start works even warning is gone

```
const app = express().enable();
```

I know this works for others by watching video online. Nobody had to add anything into import or initialisation to make that intellisense work so I guess there is some problem with setting and I just can't figure out what it is

Here are some pictures of my stetting

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Adding TypeScript definition files usually helps IDEs to resolve methods that are otherwise hard to resolve based on the static code analysis.

In WebStorm, you can press Alt-Enter on `require('express')` and select *Install TypeScript definitions for better type information* – this will download `@types/express` and configure it in the IDE. Alternatively, you can add `@types/express` to your package.json file.

Comment: Wow.. that worked perfectly for express.. I can't find that option for sequileze package though.. Do you know how to fix that? do we have to just import it with .Sequileze at the end like this `const Sequelize = require('sequelize').Sequelize`? I found this solution online but the solution is like 3 years old

Comment: Well never mind.. at least I know how to fix it for other packages... Thank you

Comment: Should be available `sequelize` as well: for https://www.npmjs.com/package/@types/sequelize

Comment: oh.. you're right.. It just not available by Alt-Enter way... Thanks